# Replace first character in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have to replace the first character in a string. I have a snippet like this:

```
 if(!([string]::Compare($filestmp.Substring(0,1), "M", $True)))
 {
     echo cos
     $filestmp = $filestmp.Replace('^(.*?)M(.*)', 'Zmodyfikowany  ')
 }
```

The code doesn't throw any exceptions, and it doesn't work either. The `if` condition passes, since my `echo` statement is printed. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? why do you have a regular expression in your code ? How do your string look before replacing ? and how do you want it after ?

Comment: `String.Replace()` doesn't support regex, use the `-replace` operator or `Regex.Replace()`

Comment: My string looks for example "M log.txt" and I want to receive "Zmodyfikowany log.txt"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RegEx is overkill.

Use a simple substring:

```
$filestmp=("Zmodyfikowany" +  $filestmp.SubString(1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution:

```
$filestmp = "M Log.txt"

# Test equal which ignores case
if ($filestmp.Substring(0,1) -ieq "M")
{
    $filestmp = "'Zmodyfikowany{0}" -f  $filestmp.Substring(1)
}

# Test like which ignores case
if ($filestmp -ilike "M*")
{
    $filestmp = "'Zmodyfikowany{0}" -f  $filestmp.Substring(1)
}
```